# ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [2] Build failed;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine

I am running google app engine - ruby on rails example all went well up to the point which i have to deploy app.

[google app engine ruby on rails tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/deploy-postgres#download_app)

here is the console output leading up to the error

```
Beginning deployment...
If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...done.

Verifying that Managed VMs are enabled and ready.
Building and pushing image for service [default]
Started cloud build [c80b8677-2cff-4341-a6f7-b97a55b5fb83].
To see logs in the Cloud Console: https://console.developers.google.com/logs?project=cloud-compute-rails&service=cloudbuild.googleapis.com&key1=c80b8677-2cff-4341-a6f7-b97a55b5fb83&logName=projects/cloud-compute-rails/logs/cloudbuild
----------------------------- REMOTE BUILD OUTPUT ------------------------------
starting build "c80b8677-2cff-4341-a6f7-b97a55b5fb83"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://staging.cloud-compute-rails.appspot.com/us.gcr.io/cloud-compute-rails/appengine/default.20160427t004918:latest#1461714651629000
Copying gs://staging.cloud-compute-rails.appspot.com/us.gcr.io/cloud-compute-rails/appengine/default.20160427t004918:latest#1461714651629000...
Downloading file:///tmp/source-archive.tgz:                      0 B/203.33 KiB Downloading file:///tmp/source-archive.tgz:                      72 KiB/203.33 KDownloading file:///tmp/source-archive.tgz:                      144 KiB/203.33 Downloading file:///tmp/source-archive.tgz:                      203.33 KiB/203.33 KiB
FETCHBUILDER
BUILD
+ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
+ cat Dockerfile
# This Dockerfile for a Ruby application was generated by gcloud.

# The base Dockerfile installs:
# * A number of packages needed by the Ruby runtime and by gems
#   commonly used in Ruby web apps (such as libsqlite3)
# * A recent version of NodeJS
# * A recent version of the standard Ruby runtime to use by default
# * The bundler gem
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/ruby

# Install 2.2.3
 if not already preinstalled by the base image
RUN cd /rbenv/plugins/ruby-build && \
    git pull && \
    rbenv install -s 2.2.3
 && \
    rbenv global 2.2.3
 && \
    gem install -q --no-rdoc --no-ri bundler --version 1.11
ENV RBENV_VERSION 2.2.3


# Copy the application files.
COPY . /app/

# Install required gems.
RUN bundle install --deployment && rbenv rehash

# BUG: Reset entrypoint to override base image.
ENTRYPOINT []

# Start application on port $PORT.
CMD bundle exec rackup -p 8080 -E production config.ru
+ docker build --tag us.gcr.io/cloud-compute-rails/appengine/default.20160427t004918:latest /workspace
Sending build context to Docker daemon 545.3 kB
Step 1 : FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/ruby
 ---> 3e6d0d6d0575
Step 2 : IF
Unknown instruction: IF
ERROR
ERROR: build step "gcr.io/cloud-builders/dockerizer" failed: exit status 1
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
```

any clues?

Comment: Any clues in the build logs?

Comment: could not get access to them. i have created a new rails project, attached an app.yaml and it worked. not sure why the google tutorials fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To fix first one( if there is no dockerfile in your application,which should be generated automatically.)

   Go to your ruby sample file which you failed to deploy. (Mine was "2-cloud-sql" like below)

   $ cd 2-cloud-sql

And I executed next command.

```
$ gcloud preview app gen-config --custom
```

If you have questioned "update now?" answer y(yes).
Then "app.yaml" file becomes custom but original is kept as written , and "dockerfile" is made.

Next I was asked to update some Cloud SDK components, so write command below.

```
$ gcloud components update
```

And I did below

```
$ bundle install
```

2. There should be already "Dockerfile" in your sample app.
   Open and see.

In my case these 3 places(in yellow square) were indented and went to next line unnaturally .~But in another google tutorial, there are no such a strange line ,so I did not need change "dockerfile" in that case.Please see dockerfile and check whether there are places to change like mine below.~

[Go and check a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdaJr.png)

So I fixed these strange parts like this.

[Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvdMc.png)

Before "if" there was a strange change of line and also before "&& \".

After fixed and saved Dockerfile

I executed these commands like google instruction.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile


$ gcloud preview app deploy
```

This is all I did, I hope it could be some help for you.

Comment: hey thank you, unfortunately i do not have the time to test this now, i created a new rails app, added the app.yaml file and it autogenerated a dockerfile on deploying. it seems to have worked but i will check your lengthy answer if i find time with fiddling with the examples again. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced on same problem with yours,and fixed it.

In my case, there were two points to fix.

1. Dockerfile has been disappeared.( Are there Dockerfile in your sample downloaded?)
2. In the Dockerfile there are strange indentions.(Maybe this causes of differences of ruby-version.)

By fixing these two points, it has worked.

I will write this procedure in details.